# Dividing the world in a thousand or so locations

Tags: algorithm, geometry, geography

Background: I want to create a weather service, and since most available APIs limit the number of daily calls, I want to divide the planet in a thousand or so areas.

Obviously, internet users are not uniformly distributed, so the sampling should be finer around densely populated regions.

How should I go about implementing this?

- Where can I find data regarding geographical internet user density?
- The algorithm will probably be something similar to k-means. However, implementing it on a sphere with oceans may be a bit tricky. Any insight?
- Finally, maybe there is a way I can avoid doing all of this?

Comment: This has the potential to be quite inaccurate. Consider an area which has a mountain on one side and a lake on the other. They may be geographically close, but the weather atop the mountain will be much different than that next to the lake. As to "avoiding doing all of this", look into [aviation weather](http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver) which covers thousands of locations around the world (for free, with bulk data feeds).

Comment: what about Hierarchical Clustering?

Comment: @TimMedora : I'm well aware of the accuracy problem, but I've yet to find a better solution. The problem with all the free feeds I've found is that they don't have forecast information, which I really need for what I have in mind.

Comment: FWIW, A TAF is a 24-36 hour forecast a variety of weather points. [Example](http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=tafs&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=true&hoursBeforeNow=2&stationString=KDE)

Comment: @TimMedora : that's almost what I want, except it unfortunately doesn't give a temperature forecast. Do you know if that would be available?

Comment: Oddly enough, temperatures are only available for observations (METARs), not forecasts. Not sure why that is. However, there *is* a web service available for temperature forecasts: http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl. I used this in a commercial product for about a year. It's only downfall was that it was much slower than a bulk feed.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to k-mean is the [centroidal Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation) (it is the continuous version of k-means). However, this would produce a uniform tesselation of your sphere that does not account for user density as you wish.

So a similar solution is the same technique but used with [a Power Diagram](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.678&rep=rep1&type=pdf) : a Power Diagram is a Voronoi Diagram that accounts for a density (by assigning a weight to each Voronoi seed). Such diagram can be computed using an embedding in a 3D space (instead of 2D) that consists of the first two (x,y) coordinates plus a third one which is the square root of [any large positive constant minus the weight for the given point].

Using that, you can obtain a tesselation of your domain accounting for a user density.

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about internet user density in general. You care about the density of users using your service - and you don't care where those users are, you care where they ask about. So once your site has been going for more than a day you can use the locations people ask about the previous day to work out what the areas should be for the next day.

Dynamic programming on a tree is easy. What I would do for an algorithm is to build a tree of successively more finely divided cells. More cells mean a smaller error, because people get predictions for points closer to them, and you can work out the error, or at least the relative error between more cells and fewer cells. Starting from the bottom up work out the smallest possible total error contributed by each subtree, allowing it to be divided in up to 1,2,3,..N. ways. You can work out the best possible division and smallest possible error for each k=1..N for a node by looking at the smallest possible error you have already calculated for each of its descendants, and working out how best to share out the available k divisions between them.

I would try to avoid doing this by thinking of a different idea. Depending on the way you look at life, there are at least two disadvantages of this:

1) You don't seem to be adding anything to the party. It looks like you are interposing yourself between organizations that actually make weather forecasts and their clients. Organizations lose direct contact with their clients, which might for instance lose them advertising revenue. Customers get a poorer weather forecast.

2) Most sites have legal terms of service, which must clients can ignore without worrying. My guess is that you would be breaking those terms of service, and if your service gets popular enough to be noticed they will be enforced against you.

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) what you have in mind? If so, then while the number of nodes in the tree is still small, your pick for the weather forecast location is going to be way off, no?

Comment: More like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree but even that is a bit misleading. The main difference from a k-d tree is that the forecast locations chosen will probably not coincide with any of the forecast locations used in queries, because they will be mesh points for a mesh size that depends on how deep a tree of successively finer meshes you have ended up with. This would work best if you actually had the co-operation of the forecasters and could use the forecast mesh as the basis for your data storage mesh.

Comment: Internet user density is a proxy for my user's density. Dynamic programming is cool, but I don't see why I would use a discrete setting when the continuous k-means would be more accurate and easier to implement. Finally, you don't know what I have in mind, how can you judge the added value of my service? Some APIs specifically allow commercial use.